# Android Alert Dialog rendered only partially

Tags: android, dialog, android-dialog

I know that this is pretty strange, but I think that I'm doing something wrong with it.

```
public void checkUpgrade( final Context context, final int PREF_ID ) {
    if (!StringHelper.isEmpty( type ) && !type.equals( TYPE_HIDDEN )) {

        if ( type.equals( TYPE_SUGGESTED ) && lastRemind + reminderInterval < System.currentTimeMillis() ) {
            return;
        }

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder( context );
        builder.setTitle( title ).setMessage( description ).setCancelable( type.equals( TYPE_SUGGESTED ) ).setPositiveButton( "Update", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                final Intent browserIntent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse( link ) );
                context.startActivity( browserIntent );
                lastRemind = Long.MAX_VALUE;
                save( context, PREF_ID );
            }
        } );
        if (type.equals( TYPE_SUGGESTED )) {
            builder.setNegativeButton( "Skip", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                    lastRemind = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    save( context, PREF_ID );
                }
            } );
        }
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }
}
```

This is the code of my alert dialog. 
I all checkUpgrade on my activity onResume. I really don't know why it render **only the Upgrade button** and not all the layout. Do you know why?

Comment: Is it possible, that your `if (type.equals( TYPE_SUGGESTED )) {` is false? I'm having a SGS2 with Android 4.0.4 and it shows both Buttons.

Comment: Maybe I explained not well. When I say partiall, I mean that it display ONLY the button and NOT the title, description and layout. Only the button! :D

Comment: Oh. Which device do you use? And what Android version? An original version or a custom one?

Comment: Galaxy Nexus with stock JB. But this happen all the time on different devices

Comment: Is it only by your Dialog? Or by other Dialogs (from other Apps) too?

Answer (score 0):

I made an AlertDialog using your code, and it displays as expected.  Do you have a custom theme defined?  If so, try using just the system default theme and see if that helps.

**More**

Okay, theme isn't your issue... what about a static layout defined in XML?

Comment: We're actually using default theme. I've also tried to use the DialogFragment instead of normal AlertFragment and I get the same result... What could be?

Comment: Anyway this appen only the first time I show the dialog, if I change orientation (and dialog is recreated) it will be rendered fine

Comment: The plot thickens.  If you have something that draws correctly after a configuration change, usually I'd suspect that somebody marked only a part of your view hierarchy as dirty, hoping it would draw the whole thing.  That is obviously not the case here.

Comment: As I said I'm actually using a totally clean DialogFragment to launch my AlertDialog. I'm using this one -> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#AlertDialog can the parent fragment layout change it's behaviour?